# No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 3, '(obj: Observable<unknown>

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs

I am trying to create a simple login logout implementation using angular as a font-and. I am stuck when I start using observable. here is my error in **nav.component.html**:-

[image]

here is my code.

**nav.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { AccountService } from '../_services/account.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  model : any = {};

  currentUser$:Observable<User>;
 

  constructor(private accountService : AccountService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentUser$=this.accountService.currentUser$;
  }

  
//clarify code
  

 

}
```

**accountservice.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../_models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {

  baseUrl='https://localhost:5001/api/';
  private currentUserSource =new ReplaySubject<User> (1);
  currentUser$=this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  

  constructor(private http :HttpClient) { }

  login(model:any)
  {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl+'account/login',model).pipe(

      map((response:User)=>{

        const user=response;
        if(user){
          localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }



  setCurrentUser(user:User)
  {
    this.currentUserSource.next(user);
  }





  logout()
  {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.currentUserSource.next(null as any);
  }
}
```

**nav.component.html**

```
//clarify code


  <form *ngIf="!currentUser$ | async" #loginForm="ngForm" class="d-flex"  (ngSubmit)="login()" autocomplete="off">
          <input 
          
           name="username"
           [(ngModel)]="model.username"
           class="form-control me-2"
           type="text"
            placeholder="username">

          <input 

            name="password"
            [(ngModel)]="model.password"
          
            class="form-control me-2"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password">

          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">LOGIN</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    
  </nav>
```

I am an absolute beginner in Angular. how I resolve this issue. please help.

Comment: *ngIf="!(currentUser$ | async)"

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `*ngIf="!currentUser$ | async"` in the if statement replace it with `*ngIf="(currrentUser$ | async) === null"` or `*ngIf="!(currentUser$ | async)"` to know if there is a current User in variable `currentUser$` or `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this not-operator like this as it doesn't work. What we have to do is surround this `(currentUser$ | async)` in parentheses and then what we want to do is check to see if the current user is equal to null. So we need to remove the not operator and then we just use three equals to see if we are equal to null instead of using the not operator here. Therefore answer is

```
(currentUser$ | async) === null
```